# QueryDsl column case sensitivity bug on identifier

Tags: hsqldb, querydsl

I have seen many post on column name case sensitivity for in memory database like hsqldb and h2.   We are using sql server camel case column names.  However, I am testing using HyperSql which is column name case sensitive.   I don't see any settings to handle column name sensitivity in hypersql except when creating the table quote the column names which will make them what ever case are inside the quotes, for example 
    Insert Into AddressType ("AddressTypeName", "CreateUser")
    Values ('Mailing', 'User')

This will create tables in hsqldb with column name AddressTypeName and CreateUser

sql server is not willing to make theirs all upper case.  As a result, when creating the columns in hsqldb I quote them which creates them in camel case.  Works good except when using Querydsl their identiifers does not quote them which then results in the lookup with upper case column names and the database now has them as camel case.

The whole problem started because QueryDsl Q types which were generated off the sql server columns has the metadata with quote columns and since sql server had them as camel case it looks them up as camel case.   But now when doing a Q type query it uses the identifier un quoted which results in a upper case lookup which fails.   I don't see any work around except to let the database make them upper case and change all the Q types to be upper case for the meta data column name look ups.

I assume this is a bug in querydsl.

Example QAddressType addMetadata.  Notice the ColumnMetadata.named("AddressTypeName")   By these being quoted the database must have them in camel case.

```
public void addMetadata() {
        addMetadata(addressTypeID, ColumnMetadata.named("AddressTypeID").withIndex(1).ofType(Types.BIGINT).withSize(19).notNull());
        addMetadata(addressTypeName, ColumnMetadata.named("AddressTypeName").withIndex(2).ofType(Types.VARCHAR).withSize(50).notNull());
ColumnMetadata.named("CreateUser").withIndex(3).ofType(Types.VARCHAR).withSize(100).notNull());
    }
```

But if I switch the database to be camel case then the queryDslTemplate call fails because it does not quote the identifier.  So in the below code .where(qAddressType.addressTypeID.eq(id)); does this in sql a.addressTypeID = 1    where a is the alias for QAddressType.  It needs to be a."addressTypeID" = 1 or else hsqldb looks it up as a.ADDDRESTYPEID =    1

private static QAddressType qAddressType = new QAddressType("a");

```
@Override
public AddressType getById(Long id) {
AddressType addressType = null;
try {
SQLQuery sqlQuery = queryDslJdbcTemplate.newSqlQuery()
.from(qAddressType)
.where(qAddressType.addressTypeID.eq(id));
addressType = queryDslJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sqlQuery, new AddressTypeProjection(qAddressType));
//the API was not throwing the Exception so let's explicitly throw it 
return addressType;
}
```

Comment: In QueryDsl when generating the Q types it has the class MetaDataExporter which has a method for apply a NamingStrategy. In NamingStrategy  I found this method:        normalizeColumnName
String normalizeColumnName(String columnName)  which has this Javadoc: 
Convert the given column name and provide the opportunity to add quoted identifiers    I believe I want to add quoted identifiers to correct my issue. The problem is I can not any documentation on how to accomplish that.  If any one understand how this is done, let me know.

Comment: I found a work around that I have been using.  I switch to H2 database because it has a flag that makes column queries case insensitive.  For example:  IGNORECASE=TRUE to the database URL (example: jdbc:h2:~/test;IGNORECASE=TRUE).  This solved my issue.